# Hash being saved to database but unable to render its values in Rails forms?

Tags: html, ruby-on-rails, ruby, database, hash

I added a new column to model `Plan`, named `:per_unit_quantities_configuration` which is a hash with `min`, `max` and `step` key/values.

```
t.jsonb "per_unit_quantities_configuration", default: {}
```

When I edit a Plan, the hash is being correctly saved to the DB (I can access each key/value from the console), but the forms are not displaying any of its values (the fields are empty).

I tried adding a `store_accessor` for the column in the `Plan` model, but it is not working:

```
store_accessor :per_unit_quantities_configuration, :min, :max, :step
```

Example of a *simple_form html* that does not display hash values:

```
<%= simple_form_for [:admin, @base_plan, @plan] do |f| %>
    <% if f.object.base_plan.per_unit? %>
    <div class="d-flex">
      <%= f.simple_fields_for :per_unit_quantities_configuration do |fields| %>
        <% if f.object.errors[:per_unit_quantities_configuration].any? %>
          <%= f.error :per_unit_quantities_configuration, id: "per_unit_price_error", class: "invalid-feedback", error_prefix: "gato" %>
        <% end %>
        <%= fields.input :min %>
        <%= fields.input :max %>
        <%= fields.input :step %>

      <% end %>
    </div>
  <% end %>
  <%= f.button :submit, class: "pull-right" %>
<% end %>
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: i think no need to wrap 3 inputs `min, max, step` in `per_unit_quantities_configuration` field since it's `store_accessor` and we can access it's attributes as normal fields

Comment: @LamPhan Thank you. I did as you suggested and now the forms are displaying the hash values, but changes are not being saved. I'm redirected to the correct view after an update (suggesting no validation errors) but the changes are not persisted.

Comment: how do you `permit` those values (on controller) ?

Comment: @LamPhan this is the first thing I went to see, but I can't spot anything wrong:  `def plan_params
    params.require(:plan).permit(
      per_unit_quantities_configuration: %i(min max step),
    )
  end`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

since you setup `store_accessor :per_unit_quantities_configuration` then you can access directly 3 attributes `min, max, step`, so that you no need to wrap those attributes on `simple_fields_for :per_unit_quantities_configuration` and treat them as normal fields (that mean on controller you have to `permit` them as normal fields)

```rb
# view
<%= f.input :min %>
<%= f.input :max %>
<%= f.input :step %>

# controller
def plan_params     
 params.require(:plan).permit(:min,:max,:step)   
end
```

Comment: Thank you, that wordked!